# Columns names of a dataframe from a list of names

Tags: pandas

I have a list of names:

```
list_names = ['Albert','Marcos','Alberta']
```

and I have an empty dataframe:

```
t=pd.DataFrame()
```

How can I add list_names as columns in the dataframe `t` with values = 10, like this:

```
Albert  Marcos   Alberta
 10      10        10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reindex` to create columns  and `loc` to append data

```
t =t.reindex(list_names, axis='columns')
t.loc[0]=10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'Albert': 10, 'Marcos': 10, 'Alberta': 10})
```